# Passing String from Native C++ DLL to C# App

Tags: c#, c++, string, visual-studio-2008, dllimport

I have written a DLL in C++. One of the functions writes to a character array.

C++ Function

```
EXPORT int xmain(int argc, char argv[], char argv2[])
{
    char  pTypeName[4096];
    ...
    //Other pTypeName ends up populated with "Portable Network Graphics"
    //This code verifies that pTypeName is populated with what I think it is:
    char szBuff[64];
    sprintf(szBuff, pTypeName, 0);
    MessageBoxA(NULL, szBuff, szBuff, MB_OK);
    //The caption and title are "Portable Network Graphics"

    ...
    //Here, I attempt to copy the value in pTypeName to parameter 3.
    sprintf(argv2, szBuff, 0);

    return ret;
}
```

C# Import

```
    //I believe I have to use CharSet.Ansi because by the C++ code uses char[],
    [DllImport("FirstDll.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern int xmain(int argc, string argv, ref string zzz);
```

C# Function

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string zzz = ""; 
    int xxx = xmain(2, @"C:\hhh.bmp", ref zzz);
    MessageBox.Show(zzz);

    //The message box displays
    //MessageBox.Show displays "IstuÈst¼ÓstÄstlÄstwÄstiÑstõÖstwÍst\
    // aÖst[ÖstÃÏst¯ÄstÐstòÄstŽÐstÅstpÅstOleMainThreadWndClass"

}
```

I have attempted to pass a parameter from C# by reference and have the C++ DLL populate the parameter. Even though I have verified that the value is correct in the DLL, gibberish gets passed to the C# application.

What can I do to write the correct string value to the C# string?

Comment: Try to create a "unsafe" space in your C# project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `StringBuilder` to pass a character array that native code can fill in (see [Fixed-Length String Buffers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h.aspx#cpcondefaultmarshalingforstringsanchor3)).

Declare the function:

```
[DllImport("FirstDll.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern int xmain(int argc, string argv, StringBuilder argv2);
```

Use it:

```
// allocate a StringBuilder with enough space; if it is too small,
// the native code will corrupt memory
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(4096);
xmain(2, @"C:\hhh.bmp", sb);
string argv2 = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: This solution solved my problem. I expected that I could use a character array like     char[] ch = new char[4096], but that failed. Any idea why?

Comment: IIRC, `char[]` is always marshalled as an array of 16-bit characters (native type `WCHAR`) and doesn't participate in the ANSI/Unicode conversion performed for `string`/`StringBuilder` by `CharSet.Ansi`. Additionally, I think that passing a `char[]` doesn't automatically pass a pointer to the first element in the array (which the C code expects); to force that to happen, you can specify the parameter as `ref char` in the `DllImport` signature and call it with `ref ch[0]` in the method call.

Answer (score 2):

Give some other information to the DLLImport call. Look at the following example of my own:

```
[DllImport("tcpipNexIbnk.dll", EntryPoint = "SendData", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int Send([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string message);
```

Notice two things, the CallingConvention parameter:
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)

Use that as it is.

And then just behind the c# string type, you can play with the different Unmanaged types using the MarshalAS instruction, that will cast your C# string parameter to the native string type you have in your c++ program:

```
public static extern int Send([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string message);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: When selecting the CallingConvention.Cdecl option, I must make sure that my DLL exports functions using __declspec (dllexport). Is that correct?     Using the MarshalAs keyword did not solve the issue by itself, but I think I will have to keep it in mind when I move to Unicode compliance.