# Changing parameters in c/c++ dll

Tags: c#, c++, c, dll

I have a DLL written in C. I have a function in this dll, for example:

```
unsigned char DLL_EXPORT getTRK(char *XML, unsigned long *Len)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, XML, "Dll message", MB_OK);
    char s[] = "Some string";
    XML = s;
    return rand()%2;
}
```

I need to change XML variable value in dll and bring this value to my C# prog. I have next code on C#:

```
[DllImport("Some_DLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern byte getTRK(string XML, uint Len);
...
string xml = "123";
uint len = 0;
tbXml.Clear();
if (getTRK(xml, len) == 0)
{
   tbXml.AppendText(xml);
}
else
{
   tbXml.AppendText("Some error!");
}
```

I've tried different ways to do it, but nothing works as needed. 
I want to get in my c# prog value for the xml variable = "Some string". How can i get it?
If i'm using ref or out like this:

```
[DllImport("Some_DLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern byte getTRK(ref string XML, ref uint Len);
...
string xml = "123";
uint len = 0;
tbXml.Clear();
if (getTRK(ref xml, ref len) == 0)
{
   tbXml.AppendText(xml);
}
else
{
   tbXml.AppendText("Some error!");
}
```

dll gets some garbage values, not "123". if i'm doing like this:

```
*XML = *s;
```

nothing happens, too.

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856127/passing-string-from-native-c-dll-to-c-sharp-app ?

Comment: This needs to start with valid C code first.  What you posted is fundamentally wrong, it needs to use strcpy_s() instead of the assignment.  Make it work in a C program before you try to interop with it.

Answer (score 2):

C# uses 2-byte character strings and marshalles them accordingly. char* is used to store 1-byte character strings. 
You have to specify charset in you your DllImport attribute and usec wchar_t* strings.

If you need to store your strings in char* you can write a custom marshaller, which is called something like this

```
void ErrorWriter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler, MarshalTypeRef = typeof(Utf8Marshaler))]string errorMessage, string taskId, ProcessType processType);
```

and implemented like this

```
internal class Utf8Marshaler : ICustomMarshaler
{
    private static Utf8Marshaler _staticInstance;

    public IntPtr MarshalManagedToNative(object managedObj)
    {
        if (managedObj == null)
            return IntPtr.Zero;
        if (!(managedObj is string))
            throw new MarshalDirectiveException(
                "UTF8Marshaler must be used on a string.");

        // not null terminated
        byte[] strbuf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes((string) managedObj);
        IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(strbuf.Length+1);
        Marshal.Copy(strbuf, 0, buffer, strbuf.Length);

        // write the terminating null
        Marshal.WriteByte(buffer + strbuf.Length, 0);
        return buffer;
    }

    public object MarshalNativeToManaged(IntPtr pNativeData)
    {
        if (pNativeData == IntPtr.Zero)
            return string.Empty;
        int length = 1;

        IntPtr offsetPtr = IntPtr.Add(pNativeData, 1);
        while (Marshal.ReadByte(offsetPtr) != 0)
        {
            offsetPtr = IntPtr.Add(offsetPtr, 1);
            length++;
        }
        byte[] strbuf = new byte[length];

        Marshal.Copy(pNativeData, strbuf, 0, length);
        string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(strbuf);
        return data;
    }

    public void CleanUpNativeData(IntPtr pNativeData)
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pNativeData);
    }

    public void CleanUpManagedData(object managedObj)
    {
    }

    public int GetNativeDataSize()
    {
        return -1;
    }

    public static ICustomMarshaler GetInstance(string cookie)
    {
        if (_staticInstance == null)
        {
            return _staticInstance = new Utf8Marshaler();
        }
        return _staticInstance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to test with cyrillic strings.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, but i found another solution. I'm using StringBuilder instead of string type. And in dll using strcpy strcpy(XML, "Some String"). And everything works correctly. Even cyrillic strings.